# VB.NET Parsing JSON - Telegram

Tags: json, vb.net, telegram

I'm trying to create a Telegram bot is VB.NET and am having trouble with parsing JSON. Firstly, here's an example of the JSON I am getting from Telegram:

```
    {
        "ok": true,
        "result": [
            {
                "update_id": 999999999,
                "message": {
                    "message_id": 99,
                    "from": {
                        "id": 999999999,
                        "first_name": "Adam",
                        "last_name": "Taveirne",
                        "username": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "language_code": "en-US"
                    },
                    "chat": {
                        "id": 99999999,
                        "first_name": "Adam",
                        "last_name": "Taveirne",
                        "username": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "type": "private"
                    },
                    "date": 1500281934,
                    "text": "Hello"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'm struggling to find help on parsing JSON that's formatted like this. Whenever I try to parse the result array, I get a "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array" error.

I've tried a bunch of different code and get similar errors but this is what my most recent try looks like:

```
Sub Main()

//Crap cut out here...

Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyTeleJSON)(json)

End Sub

Public Class MyTeleJSON
    Public Property ok As String
    Public Property result As MyTeleUpdates
End Class

Public Class MyTeleUpdates
    Public Property update_id As String
    Public Property message_id As String
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property first_name As String
    Public Property last_name As String
    Public Property username As String
    Public Property text As String
    Public Property ok As String
End Class
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction please as i'm really struggling with this JSON stuff!

Many thanks

Adam

Comment: Note that your JSON has a `message` property that a bunch of your properties should be inside.  If you're having problems visualising classes to match some JSON, there are tools like [jsonutils](https://jsonutils.com/) that can help.  For instance, given your JSON above, it's generating 5 classes to hold it correctly.

Comment: I have tried it with 5 classes too and get the same message... It makes no sense to me as I really don't understand JSON.

Comment: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array into type 'x.Module1+MyTeleUpdates' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {""name"":""value""}) to deserialize correctly." & vbCrLf & "To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {""name"":""value""}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array." & vbCrLf & "Path 'result', line 1, position 21."

Comment: Change to `Public Property result As List(Of MyTeleUpdates)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the needed classes. It's possible that your "ok" propery broke the parsing at it is a boolean.

```
Public Class From
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property first_name As String
    Public Property last_name As String
    Public Property username As String
    Public Property language_code As String
End Class

Public Class Chat
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property first_name As String
    Public Property last_name As String
    Public Property username As String
    Public Property type As String
End Class

Public Class Message
    Public Property message_id As Integer
    Public Property from As From
    Public Property chat As Chat
    Public Property date As Integer
    Public Property text As String
End Class

Public Class Result
    Public Property update_id As Integer
    Public Property message As Message
End Class

Public Class Example
    Public Property ok As Boolean
    Public Property result As List(of Result)
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like that was it all along!